# Can anyone explain me how does :hard_wrap work?

Tags: ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I don't undestand how to create a new line using Markdown Redcarpet.
I type

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

But I see

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

In my helper I have `markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(MarkdownRenderer, hard_wrap: true, autolink: true, space_after_headers: true)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Redcarpet manual, the `auto_wrap` option goes into the Renderer initializer like this:

```rb
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(hard_wrap: true), autolink: true, space_after_headers: true)

puts markdown.render("Line 1\n Line 2")
```

which gives me this output

```html
<p>Line 1<br>
 Line 2</p>
```

https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#darling-i-packed-you-a-couple-renderers-for-lunch

Please note that I couldn't find a `MarkdownRenderer` class as Redcarpet comes only with a `Redcarpet::Render::HTML` and `Redcarpet::Render::XHTML` built in renderer.

Comment: it's strange. Because adding a commet with "Line 1\n Line 2" it doesn't work. It shows exactly "Line 1\n Line 2"